# Install MySQL Plugin on Wamp

Tags: mysql, wamp

I've downloaded the windows binary from http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/ but I'm having trouble installing it.

If I run the command `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  '%plugin%'` it outputs the directory 'c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.20/plugin' so this is where I placed the 2 dll files.

I restarted the server and then tried:

```
USE mysql;
CREATE FUNCTION lib_mysqludf_preg_info RETURNS STRING SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_preg.dll';
```

But MySQL just said: *#1126 - Can't open shared library 'lib_mysqludf_preg.dll' (errno: 2 )*

What am I missing?

MySQL version is 5.5.20

Comment: are you sure that you use the right directory ? This kind of behavior happens when we have several version of WAMP installed .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to install the windows binary on Wamp, but I got the same error message as you.

I think that the 64-bit version of Wamp is still not supported by the standard compiled binary you can download from http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/. I tried to disinstall the 64-bit version of Wamp, and installed the 32-bit version instead, and I was able to make it work using the following steps:

- Copy the library `libpcre.dll` to the MySql bin directory (e.g. `c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin`)
- Copy the library `lib_mysqludf_preg.dll` to the MySql plugin directory (e.g. `c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\lib\plugin`)

and then you can launch this:

```
USE mysql;
CREATE FUNCTION lib_mysqludf_preg_info RETURNS STRING SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_preg.dll';
CREATE FUNCTION preg_capture RETURNS STRING SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_preg.dll';
CREATE FUNCTION preg_check RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_preg.dll';
CREATE FUNCTION preg_replace RETURNS STRING SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_preg.dll';
CREATE FUNCTION preg_rlike RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_preg.dll';
CREATE FUNCTION preg_position RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_preg.dll';
```

to me it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

Leave `lib_mysqludf_preg.dll` at `plugin_dir`

and move `libpcre.dll` to `{MySQL Server}\bin`

Then, execute `"CREATE FUNCTION ...",`